# for looping over an array

Tags: arrays, bash, for-loop, whitespace

I am trying to resolve an issue with a bash script that is intended to search through each users home directory in /Users/ and find two different directories, stored in array "SUBDIRS." If these directories exist, I want to remove with the recursive and force options. If they do not exist I want the script to continue looking for the next directory, next home folder, etc.

```
#!/bin/sh


err=0




SUBDIRS=(
    "Library/Application Support/Spotify"
    "Library/Caches/com.spotify.client"
)


for HOMEDIR in /Users/*; do

    for SUBDIR in ${SUBDIRS}; do

        DIR="${HOMEDIR}/${SUBDIR}"

            if [[ -d "${DIR}" ]]; then
                rm -rf "${DIR}"
                echo "${HOMEDIR}/${SUBDIR} has been removed."
                APP=$(find "${HOMEDIR}" -name [sS]potify.app)
                rm -rf "${APP}"
            fi

    done

done

exit $err
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to signify that it's an array to be expanded (and quote it).

```
for SUBDIR in "${SUBDIRS[@]}"; do
```

You should quote the pattern in the `find` command so `find` will expand it instead of the shell.

```
APP=$(find "${HOMEDIR}" -name '[sS]potify.app')
```

Comment: He should also use `-exec rm` or `-delete` with the find command. It isn't required since the -name arg wouldn't allow names with spaces though.

Comment: @jordanm: `-name` allows names with spaces

Comment: `-name` does, but not with the OP's pattern. I could have worded that better.

Comment: @jordanm Why doesn't single quotes in the find command make the enclosed literal. I thought that anything inside of single quote is not subject to expansion and interpreted as literal? Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @DeanA.Vassallo The arg in single quotes is literal, but the pattern that it matches isn't always. Eg. if the pattern was '*.app', it could match "foo bar.app", which would get word split on the array assignment to two elements, "foo" and "bar.app". With a pattern that will not match files with spaces, it isn't an issue, but still generally better to use -exec.

Comment: @jordanm that makes perfect sense. Thank you again. This was extremely helpful.

Comment: @DeanA.Vassallo: Normally, the shell would expand a glob pattern, but `find` can do so as well. By using single quotes, expansion is delayed for `find` to do it snd not the shell.